# Numerating tables, examples etc

Tags: numbering

I am new to LaTeX and trying to get my head around a number of things. I have a number of examples and table throughout my report that I want to be able to call thing like Example 1.3, Table 2.1, Figure 2.3 etc.

I was wondering if there was any way that these could be numerated automatically, ie would change to fit the chapter they were in.

Thanks

Comment: use `\label` in the table or example environment and `\ref` to reference them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: What do the prefix numbers (e.g., the "1" in "1.3") refer to: chapter numbers, section numbers, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\chapter{zz}

zz zz zzzzzz

\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{cc}
1&22\\
33&4
\end{tabular}
\caption{some numbers\label{ttt}}

\end{table}

\begin{example}\label{ee}
some stuff
\end{example}

see table \ref{ttt} and example \ref{ee}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after, what does the [ht] after table do?

Comment: @TomMounsey - `h` stands for "here" and `t` stands for "top". See the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001) for a discussion of LaTeX's algorithm(s) for placing floats such as `table`s and `figure`s.

Comment: Ok cheers. Sorry, just another quick question. I'm trying to write within the example without using italics which seems t automatically be on. Is there anyway of changing this?

Comment: @TomMounsey there are a lot of packages that enhance "theorem" definitions have a look at `texdoc amsthm` for example, which has several predefined styles (italic or not) and a way of defining new styles.